# 1995 Subaru impreza acceleration problem

Tags: subaru, manual-transmission, acceleration, impreza

I recently brought a 95 Subaru impreza 1.6 ltr 5 speed manual. I put my foot down on accelerator and it spits and splutters. If i put my foot down slowly I can get up to speed, but once I'm at say 100 or 110 kph every minute or so it starts to die down. I take my foot off and re-apply slowly. It slowly picks up but happens every minute or so. I have changed plugs, air filter leads and fuel filter.

Please help me.

Comment: Check spark plug wires, distributor cap and rotor, ignition coil.

Comment: When was the last time it was tuned up; plugs, wires, PCV, fuel filter, air filter, etc?

Answer (score 2):

This is typical of a fuel delivery issue. The only advice I could give you is test, exhaust back pressure, fuel pressure and intake vacuum. Make sure those numbers are correct.

If they are all within acceptance, you need to look into testing the head gasket and the engine block itself for leaks. although those cars are great and rarely have problems. They are prone to some catalytic converter clogging issues.